# Config Apache 2.2

Tags: apache, config

I have installed Apache. When I go to localhost, that I see IIS7 page. Maybe this appear because I have installed SQLServer before. How can I config again to run apache, please tell me.

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably, you still have IIS installed. Try uninstalling it.